# React Native CameraRoll: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Operation not permitted

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, camera-roll

I want to save the images in the cameraRoll and I am using @react-native-community/cameraroll.
To install the package I ran:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/cameraroll
```

in `settings.gradle` file I added:

```
include ':@react-native-community_cameraroll'
project(':@react-native-community_cameraroll').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,    '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cameraroll/android')
```

I ran

```
yarn add fbjs
```

because I had the error in this link:
https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/issues/352

I added these permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the application tag of AndroidManifest

This is my code:

```
import CameraRoll from "@react-native-community/cameraroll";

async function hasAndroidPermission() {
  const permission = PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

  const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(permission);
  if (hasPermission) {
    return true;
  }

  const status = await PermissionsAndroid.request(permission);
  return status === 'granted';
}
const savePicture = async (path,album)=>{
  if (Platform.OS === "android" && !(await hasAndroidPermission())) {
    return;
  }
  CameraRoll.save(path, {album})
}
```

When I call savePicture I have this warning:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Operation not permitted
```

When I test this in android 9/10 I have no problems. With android 11/12 I have the warning and the pictures doesn't save.
React-native version: 0.68.2

Someone can help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for permission in react native [react-native-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions).
It will work on both android and iOS.

Comment: I tryed but the warning persists. The permission is granted but when I try to save images it show me the warning.